# How to search terminal output

Tags: ubuntu

Suppose I have a Terminal open that contains thousands of lines of output from my previous commands over the past few hours/days.  How do I search that recorded output for a string?  I'm especially interested in a solution that doesn't require the mouse.

I know I should have used tee, but that's not always convenient.

I know I could "Select All", then open an editor, paste, then search, but I'm hoping for something simpler (and Select All seems to require the mouse).

I was hoping there would be a "Find..." command in the menu bar (like Mac OS X has).

Comment: I didn't even realize there was a "Find..." command until you mentioned it in OS X, so +1 to this question for being the answer to my Googling.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Finding text in scrollback is a weakness of most terminal emulators; the only ones I know of that provide it are OS X Terminal and [Terminator](https://code.google.com/p/jessies/).  That said, you could run [GNU screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) in any terminal and search its scrollback buffer in copy mode.

Comment: Thanks geekosaur.  I also just found this 'idea' on the ubuntu site, which just seems to confirm that it is impossible as of yet: http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/9841/

Comment: Just adding that you can use Byobu which based on TMux or Screen

Comment: Terminator doesn't highlight text when you search for it.

Comment: Do you happen to recall how to find text in the OS X Terminal?  I'm trying to do that right now, and I'm having difficulty successfully searching out this information.

Answer (score 73):

If you are running a gnome-terminal (default GUI terminal on ubuntu) you can hit `shift+ctrl+f`, type your search terms, and hit enter. Still graphical, but no mouse required.

Comment: Thanks SynapticUnderrun, but your tip doesn't seem to work for me. I'm using a fresh install of ubuntu 10.4.

Comment: This works on ubuntu 10.10 and 11.04. I'm running 10.10 right now and using gnome-terminal 2.32.0 so perhaps upgrading gnome-terminal would help. Since this uses a gtk pop-up window to enter in search text, you will have to be running X for it to work. But you don't need to use the mouse and it will search the entire terminal buffer (which you can set to unlimited in the Edit->Profile Preferences dialog).

Comment: Thanks SynapticUnderrun, I'll definitely look for that next time I can upgrade.

Comment: Just worked for me also in `xfce4-terminal`, (X)ubuntu Raring 13.04. Thanks.

Comment: works for http://konsole.kde.org

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Works for me on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 15):

Shortcut to find string inside the terminal data : **ctrl + shift + f**

Comment: Works with default `xfce4-terminal 0.6.3` on `Xubuntu 16.04`.

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered using pipe and grep?

```
YourCommand | grep str
```

Hope this helps

Comment: He asked for searching in output of already run commands and also mentioned that tee is not always convenient to use and so is grep!

Comment: This question came up when i googled 'search terminal output' and I think this answer is great, it really helped me out (even if it technically wasn't suitable for OP)

Comment: This will not work for `awk | grep bugs` need to use `awk --help | grep bugs` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try konsole in kde. It works with gnome/unity too. Program the Find shortcut to alt-f or ctrl-f, it can search forward or backward, plus it will highlight new output that matched the searching pattern.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using terminal on Mac OS, you can simply use `Command ⌘  F`

Answer (score 0):

For the logs: also `guake` supports searching via `ctrl+shift+f` since https://github.com/Guake/guake/pull/1533 was merged